# Print all Symfony2 forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I currently have a script in Symfony where I generate a form in a controller. This form shows the content of the Entity "Page". If the user edits the form, and submits it, the form adjusts the corresponding data in the database.

```
  /**
 * Webpage allowing user to edit a page and her attributes
 *
 * @Route("/edit")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    /*
     * Get an array of all the current pages stored in the database.
     *
     * foreach loop through each website and create a seperate form for them
     *
     */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pages = $em->getRepository(Page::class)->findAll();


    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $editform= $this->createFormBuilder($page)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('location', 'url')
            ->add('displayTime', 'integer')
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Edit page'
        ))

            ->getForm();

        $editform->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editform->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->flush();
            return new Response('Page edited successfully - immediately effective');
        }

    }



    return $this->render('WalldisplayBundle:Walldisplay:edit.html.twig',
        array(
            'editform' => $editform->createView()
        ));
}
```

Unfortunately, this only prints a form with the last entry in the database. What I'd like is to have a form created for -every- entry in the database, not just the last one. I've tried iterating through  the Doctrine repository, no luck however. How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will work. I have not tested.

```
/**
 * Webpage allowing user to edit a page and her attributes
 *
 * @Route("/edit")
 */
public function editAction(Request $request)
{
    /*
     * Get an array of all the current pages stored in the database.
     *
     * foreach loop through each website and create a seperate form for them
     *
     */
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $pages = $em->getRepository(Page::class)->findAll();


    foreach ($pages as $key=>$page) {
        $editforms[$key] = $this->createFormBuilder($page)
            ->add('name', 'text')
            ->add('location', 'url')
            ->add('displayTime', 'integer')
            ->add('save', 'submit', array(
            'label' => 'Edit page'
        ))

            ->getForm();

        foreach($editforms as $editform){
            $editform->handleRequest($request);

            if ($editform->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->flush();

        }

        }

        return new Response('Page edited successfully - immediately effective');


    }

    foreach($editforms as $editform){
            $editform->handleRequest($request);

            if ($editform->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->flush();

    }
    foreach($editforms as $editform){
        $arrayForm[$editform] = $editform->createView();   
    }
    return $this->render('WalldisplayBundle:Walldisplay:edit.html.twig', $arrayForm);
}
```